# Guardar el dato de un Input de formulario a un vector en JS

Tags: javascript

El problema que ocurre es que, cuando quiero enviar el dato del formulario a un array, se borra. Lo que quiero hacer es que no se borre, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? ya que el resultado que  obtengo es un valor vacío en el vector y quiero ese dato para poder guardarlo en el vector.

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById("form");
const vector = [];
var dato;

function agregar() {
  vector.push(this.value);
  console.log(vector);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

  var itemLabel = document.createElement('label');
  itemLabel.textContent = 'Ingrese nombre:';
  formulario.appendChild(itemLabel);

  var itemInput = document.createElement('input');
  formulario.appendChild(itemInput);
  itemInput.onchange = agregar;

}
console.log(vector);
```

```html
<form action="" action="" method="" id="form">
  <input type="submit">  
</form>
```

Comment: Por favor, reformula tu pregunta, incluyendo el título. No se comprende bien qué estás queriendo hacer o cuál es el problema que tenés. Además, ¿estás agregando formularios o campos dinámicamente?

Answer (score 1):

### Observaciones:

En realidad hay que tener en cuenta que el evento "onchange" no es un buen evento para trabajar si no estas en un virtual DOM (es decir si no estas utilizando REACT u otros frameworks/librerias)

Otra cosa importante es tratar de separar la funcionalidad de agregar items al array del evento submit. Una cosa es agregar info al formulario y otra cosa es enviarla. Está explicado paso por paso en los comentarios del código, espero que te sirva, cualquier cosa me avisas y lo vemos más en detalle.

### Respuesta:

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById("form");
//Este elemento es solo para visualizar itemLabel e itemInput separado del boton submit
var inputArea = document.getElementById('container')
//Este elemento se encargará de añadir los valores al array
var addButton = document.getElementById('addButton')

const vector = []

function agregar() {
  //conviene que utilices esta función específicamente para un solo elemento en particular, si utilizas "this" dependiendo del lugar donde lo apliques puede darte problemas.
  vector.push(itemInput.value)
  //Se agrega un alert a modo de notoficación nada más.
  alert(`Item: ${itemInput.value} agregado`)
}

//quité el for porque no afectaba al desarrollo del ejemplo.

// for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
var itemLabel = document.createElement('label')
var itemInput = document.createElement('input')

itemLabel.textContent = 'Ingrese nombre: '
inputArea.appendChild(itemLabel)

//Se quita el eventListener "onchange" de este item ya que html toma el evento 
//"onchange" solo cuando quitas el foco del input y no queda claro para el ususario
inputArea.appendChild(itemInput) 

//Este es el cambio más importante, agregar un botón con type="button" que se encargue de ejecutar la función agregar.
//el evento onclick te permite agregar elementos al array sin hacer "submit" lo cual 
//te permite agregar cuantos elementos quieras antes de enviar el formulario.
addButton.onclick = agregar
// }

//Se agrega el eventlistener "load" para ejecutar la siguiente función solo cuando se terminan de cargar todos los elementos HTML. 
//(se puede sacar para ver el error que da normalmente)
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  //Se agrega un eventlistener al evento "submit" del botón formulario
  formulario.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    //Se previene el comportamiento por default
    e.preventDefault();
    //acá haces lo que quieras con la información formulario 
    console.log(vector);
  })
});
```

```html
<form action="" action="" method="" id="form">
  <div>
    <div id='container'></div>
    <button type="button" id='addButton'>Add</button>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">  
</form>
```

Comment: Podrías dejar documentación que respalde que usar onchange no es bueno para trabajar si no se usa un dom virtual? Me parece algo erroneo y poco ilógico ya que es un evento de javascript vanilla y la mayoría de frameworks realmente basan gran parte de su contenido en Proxy y emisión de eventos, no onchange.
Creo que solo pueden haber malas implementaciones de onchange cuando en realidad se necesita otro evento.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tomar el siguiente ejemplo como base y adaptarlo a tus necesidades, todo lo escencial está acá.

```js
// Utilizamos querySelectorAll para traer todos los inputs dentro del form mediante un selector similar al css
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form#form input')
var all_inputs = []

// recorrimos todos los inputs que hay dentro 
inputs.forEach(element => {
  // Acá recorremos los inputs, puedes utilizar getAtrribute para traer cualquier valor del input, puedes crear un objeto clave valor o lo que se te ocurra.
  let val = element.getAttribute('value')
  // dado que tendremos un input para el submit, en este ejemplo en particular dicho input no tiene el atributo value, por ende, si es null, no lo agregamos a nuestro vector
  if(val != null){
    all_inputs.push(val)
  }
})

// mostramos el resultado
console.log('Input value' , all_inputs)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" action="" method="" id="form">
    <input type="text" value="César" >
    <input type="text" value="Mora">
    <input type="submit">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```